# jquery ajax returns doc type and a bunch of other things I don't want

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to get some data through ajax and I for whatever reason, I am getting the doctype, the title, meta data... and the data I want. All I want is the JSON data. I am using joomla 1.5

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        jQuery('#catagoryChange').click(
            function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery.getJSON("index.php?option=com_test&task=aJax&tmpl=component")
                    .success(function(data) {alert(data.myName); })
                    .error(function(data) {alert("error"); });
            } // end of function event
        ); // end of click
    } // end of function 
); // end of document.ready
```

my function that is suppose to echo only the json:

```
function testAxaj() {
    $json = '
    {
        "myName": "Testing"
    }
    ';

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $json;
}
```

And this is what it returns

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" >
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="joomla, Joomla" />
  <meta name="description" content="Joomla! - the dynamic portal engine and content management system" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! 1.5 - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>Administration</title>
  <link href="/Test/administrator/templates/khepri/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/includes/js/joomla.javascript.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Test/media/system/js/mootools.js"></script>


<link href="templates/khepri/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="templates/khepri/css/component.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body class="contentpane">


        {
            "myName": "Testing"
        }

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, apparently it's trying to return HTML.  What does the server-side code look like? Could you make a separate php page that only returns the JSON?

Comment: I could but I do not want to go that route, I am trying to stick with the rest of the flow of my document which is MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I needed to use the php exit function after the echo:

```
function testAxaj() {
    $json = '
    {
        "myName": "Testing"
    }
    ';

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo $json;
    exit;
}
```

Works perfect now! :-)

Answer (score 1):

That looks more like a Joomla issue to me. You will need to configure it not display the HTML template at all.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the php function to:

```
function testAxaj() {
    $json = array("myName" => "Testing");

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: I do like this syntax better though. Much cleaner.

Comment: @milan try changing you jQuery function to `$.getJSON("index.php?option=com_test&task=aJax&tmpl=component", [], function(data){alert(data.myName);});`

Comment: I figured it out already, I needed to add the php function exit. See my answer above.